# Change GRASS module default parameter

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I´m new to Qgis and GRASS.
I need to change the default parameter skip of the module r.to.vect.lines, from its default value of 10 to 1.

How can I do this?

```
r.to.vect.lines [-v] input=name output=name [skip=integer] [--help] [--verbose] [--quiet] [--ui]
```

Comment: Not completely sure but if you run the standalone GRASS application and find the `r.to.vect.lines` tool, there may be an option to change the parameter there. You could also access the tool inside QGIS via the GRASS Shell and type `r.to.vect.lines` to load the tool. Again, I can't guarantee if this will help.